# Knockout JS Computed Array: Invalid Object Initializer

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am getting back a JSON data from an API and I want to compute the total cost for all the 'cost' field in the InvestmentSummary.InvestmentDetails array.
I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: invalid object initializer;
Bindings value: totalCost
```

My viewModel code looks like this:

```
        var init = { InvestmentSummary: { InvestmentDetails: [] } };
        ko.mapping.fromJS(init, {}, self);

        self.totalCost = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                var result = 0;
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.InvestmentSummary.InvestmentDetails, function () {
                    result += item.Cost();
                });
                return result;
            }
        },self); 

        self.createBtnClick = function () {
            self.layoutView(true);
            var investAPI = "some_api";
            $.getJSON(investAPI, function (result) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);   
            });
        };
```

My JSON data looks like:

```
{
   InvestmentSummary: {
     InvestmentDetails: [
     {
        Cost: 0
     },
     {
        Cost: 1
     }]
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without your full structure, but here are a couple of things that you would want to update:

- `InvestmentDetails` will be an observableArray after going through mapping, so in your `arrayForEach` you will want the first argument to be `self.InvestmentSummary.InvestmentDetails()`, so that you can loop on the underlying array.
- in the function being run on each detail, you are accessing `item.Cost()`, you will need to pass `item` into that function as the only argument.
- when you are updating the data with the mapping plugin, you can omit the second argument (mapping options), if the structure has already been created.

Here is a fiddle with these updates: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6dqfC/